# Android TextView not visible on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, visibility, textview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm having issues displaying text on Jelly Bean 4.1 and 4.2 devices. This is a screenshot from my app when you open it for the first time. Nothing has been touched.

[image: Emulator screenshots 4.1 to 4.3]

As you can see 4.1 and 4.2 is not displaying any text. I'm not using a custom font or anything like that. Here's my xml for the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:text="test"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/card_days_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textPrim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textColor="#393939"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
    android:textSize="36sp" />
```

What could be the problem? Has anyone else had this issue? I tried googling a bit but nothing came up. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed", try removing it

Comment: @for3st I tried removing it but there's no difference. sans-serif-condensed was added in 4.1 so it most likely isn't related to the issue.

Comment: so and on which sdk does it work?

Comment: @f0r3st It works on 4.3 as seen in the screenshot and also on 4.4

Comment: @SweSnow Add the whole xml layout for row.

Comment: same thing happened to me, I guess it's a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to debug using the "Hierarchy View" - Perspective in Eclipse? Usually this helps a lot, as you can read the layout properties determined during rendering.